# How to set request.getSession().setAttribute(obj, obj) within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, scriptlet

I want to set the value of a javascript variable into the jsp request/session via **request.getSession().setAttribute(obj, obj)**, so that I can use it later.

I wrote below piece of code,

```
function setVal(cache){
    var vo = cache;
    String voStr = vo;
    <% request.getSession().setAttribute("single_"%>+voStr+<%,  "true"); %>
}
```

Here, I called the '**setVal**' func, by the onclick event of a button and there's no error showing in the syntax, so I hope the syntax is correct.
But while I'm running the jsp, it's causing **JasperException**/ **ServletException** in the console.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 46 in the jsp file: /home.jsp
The method setAttribute(String, Object) in the type HttpSession is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Can anyone please suggest, how can I set value in the ***request.getSession().setAttribute*** , via a javascript function.

Comment: What you're trying to do here doesn't make any sense. JavaScript runs in a _browser_. Java runs on a _server_. You can't run Java code inside a JavaScript function. You'll have to find another way to communicate between the page and the server.

Comment: I want to set the value of a js-variable in the setAttribute(). So that I can get it later.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. But the way you are attempting to do it is illogical. It's like trying to hand something to your friend when they're on the other side of the country. The JavaScript code and Java code run in completely different places, so you can't just pass a value from one to the other like you are trying to do here.

Comment: ya,, understood. I'm confused, how to achieve so. Here the scenario is, the application is using a `table.tag` file whose purpose is to construct tables in jsp pages at runtime, by populating values from database. The file has only **<table>** tag and I want to assign some computed value onload of this **table.tag** file. But I couldn't do so, because **<table>** doesn't support javascript onload event. Hence I thought of assigning that value via `request.getSession().setAttribute()` . But still I couldn't do so. Can you give any idea, how can I resolve this.